# How to close questions that are spam of some sort?

Tags: support, close-reasons

In the good old days I could close as not a real question and move on.

Now I get the pleasure of writing a detailed reason it's off topic.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472712/actually-a-serious-about-the-programming-languages-which-i-cant-find-an-answer?noredirect=1#comment25391204_17472712 (not actually a serious question about programming languages).

> [image]

Obviously I flagged the question but I would also like to do my civic duty and close the question ASAP.  Right now the question is at -12 downvotes, and only has one close vote, mine. This seems to be an unintended change in workflow/design from pre-close-overhaul, when questions like this would be closed aggressively, in addition to flagging and soon deleting.

**I think this question stayed open longer than it would have pre-close overhaul.**  Yes, we flagged aggressively and partly due to meta attention the question was deleted aggressively enough, but I would have expected a question at -13 votes, especially one that is spam or offensive, to be closed more aggressively.

For some odd reason I actually bothered to explain all of this to the OP. #bestpractice

Comment: You **flag** spam. With a spam flag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters edited. Obviously I did that. I would also like to close the question before a moderator gets to it.

Comment: You stil flag it, if enough people flag it'll be auto-deleted.

Comment: It wasn't spam, it didn't advertise anything. However the "it is not welcome in our community" flag fits in that case as it used offensive language.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd not spam in the SO sense I guess, although spam in other colloquial use, especially on forums.  "scratch my balls" didn't particularly offend me so I didn't think to use that reason.

Comment: Added screenshot for sake of others so they can understand what we're talking about.

Answer (score 8):

If a question actually fits the spam or offensive flag reasons, then using those flags is sufficient and you don't need to close. Six of those flags will auto-delete, that is usually quicker than closing and regular deletion.

Comment: I had the honor to cast the 6th offensive flag. :)

Comment: Yeah - so we got it in 17 minutes on holiday when it was at -13 downvotes.  I think it was open longer than it would have been pre-close overhaul, and as noted, it would probably have lingered a bit longer without attention from meta.

Comment: @djechlin that's one of the reasons why we have meta, right? :)